# Inner Class em Java, quando usar?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Às vezes encontro códigos de classes com *inner class*, tais como:

```java
class ClasseExterna {

    private int a = 10;
    // ...

    class InnerClass {  

        public void accessOuter() {
            System.out.println("Outra classe  " + a);
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Sempre me pergunto:

Por que e quando devo utilizar *inner class*?
Ainda não me deparei com uma situação que não existia outra alternativa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normalmente a finalidade de uma *Inner class* é para separar as funcionalidades para deixar o código mais organizado, ou quando a funcionalidade específica necessita de uma classe separada, porém é muito específico para ser criada uma classe separada.

Um exemplo que posso citar é uma classe que implementa `Iterable` e é declarado o `Iterator` como uma *Inner class*.

Um exemplo desse caso pode ser visto na classe `java.util.ArrayList` (removi a implementação para não ficar muito longo):

```java
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}

private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Existe sempre uma alternativa para a classe interna.

Em geral, usamos uma classe interna quando você precisa acessar atributos / métodos não-públicos.

A documentação oficial extrato :

> Use a non-static nested class (or inner class) if you require access
>   to an enclosing instance's non-public fields and methods. Use a static
>   nested class if you don't require this access.

Obviamente, nós não criar uma classe interna, se você sabe, pode ser necessário em outros lugares.